# Setting up the range in the criteria section of sumif formula

Tags: arrays, excel, range, sumifs

I would like to see the sum of B given it is in the range from 17-Feb to 23-Feb.

```
A        B
17-Feb   5.00     
19-Feb   12.00
22-Feb   7.00
26-Feb   10.00
```

My estimations so far:

```
=sumif(A:A,????, B:B)
```

How do I set up a criteria which would take values from 17-Feb to 23-Feb?

I also tried `=sum(sumif(A:A,{17-Feb;?;?;23-feb}, B:B)` but it wouldn't let me.

Particularly the problem is in entering the date in the array.

Answer (score 1):

You need `SUMIFS` to accomplish this...

Try this:

```
=SUMIFS(B:B,A:A,">=2014/02/17",A:A,"<=2014/02/23")
```

Hope this does the trick